# Greedy algorithm Python. Get all sequences

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Trying to get through **DP and Greedy algorithms**. Please help!

Input has time, range and price. For eg. - (start, end, price) `[(0,1,9), (0,3,8),(2,6,5),....(6,11,10)]`. If `days_for_trading=2`, program should give the **highest profit**, which are `(0,1,9),(6,11,10)`. But it stops on the first satisfied condition with days range `(0,1,9), (2,6,5)`.

Don't know really how to make this iterating further. Thanks!

Updates: Thanks for all participants. It's solved. But the current algorithm doesn't fit the limit of memory usage. I kept the link to the task in comments below if someone needs it

```
def get_max(tmp, days_for_trading):
    global best_profit
    for day_start, day_end, price in tmp:
        traiding_sequence=[]
        cur_profit=0
        count=0
        deal=(day_start, day_end, price)
        traiding_sequence.append(deal)
        cur_profit+=price
        for next_day_start, next_day_end, next_price in tmp:    
            if days_for_trading==len(traiding_sequence):
                break
            else:
                if next_day_start>traiding_sequence[count][1]:
                    next_deal=(next_day_start, next_day_end, next_price)
                    traiding_sequence.append(next_deal)
                    cur_profit+=next_price
                    count+=1        
        best_profit=cur_profit if cur_profit>best_profit else best_profit
```

Comment: your question is not easy to follow: please provide clear expected and actual input(s) and output(s)

Comment: For d trading days, is the program just trying to find the d triplets that when we sum their prices we get the max?  If so would you get the max by sorting them in descending order by price and take the first d triplets?  Or am I missing the meaning of the start, end in the each triple?

Comment: @notacorn, I tried) tmp =[(0,2,2),(2,3,4)(5,6,3),.....] where in (start day, end day, price), time range should'nt overlap, (0-1, 2-4, 5-6), and days_for_trading=1<n<10^6, how much elements from tmp I can take. Output best_profit=int. For example days_for_trading=2, tmp=[ (0,2,6),(2,3,4)(5,6,7)], best_profit=6+7=13

Comment: @DarrylG, thank you kindly, sir. It was a nice idea, I have sorted tmp even by two parameters, and I found a mistake. It helped for the initial tests. But I got failure with memory usage on big numbers. So obviously I don't have enough knowledge for this task. I'll keep it for the future

Comment: @Mozzy_Tron--I think the issue is I'm not quite sure of the problem or the constraints.  Each triplet is a (start, end, price).  Do we have a different triplet for each day, or can the triplets start and end overlap?  For the ones that overlap can we then choose only one of them?  So for d days are we trying to find the best d non-overlapping triplets.

Comment: @DarrylG, there are plenty of overlapping triplets. Yes, exactly, we need to get the most valuable sequence. If you became interested in the task, please check this https://codeforces.com/contest/391/problem/F3

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is this line as you are excluding the last trading sequence with it (and there there is a typo in your variable)

```
if days_for_trading==len(traiding_sequence):
    break
```

try it with

```
if days_for_trading > len(traiding_sequence):
    break
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need this cause traiding_sequence needs to append as many elements as days_for_trading allows for maximum profit